# else block being executed when first condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know there's a bunch of these type of questions but I can't find one that answers the underlying issue.

I have a simple block of code where the IF condition is true but then the else block executes anyway. I have checked in the debug console that the condition is indeed true.

```
    if (@Model.MajorAvailable.ToString().ToLower() == 'true') {
        $("#checkyes").attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#checkno").attr('checked', true);
    }
```

Comment: it's impossible for this to happen. what is the output of `console.log(@Model.MajorAvailable.ToString().ToLower())`

Comment: other elements in your app are behaving unexpectedly - what you have pasted has no problems.

Comment: May we look at the place from which this block of code is called? Looks like it's either a loop with some weird checks, or you modify your `checkno` elsewhere.

Comment: @Dan Yeah it's probably that

Comment: @Lukasz032 it's just in the document ready section in the scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
if (@Model.MajorAvailable.ToString().ToLower() == true) {
    $("#checkyes").attr('checked', true);
} else {
    $("#checkno").attr('checked', true);
}
```

this code looks right but as @Bravo said  still you are comparing string with boolean value. @Model.MajorAvailable.ToString().ToLower() this line returns stirng right?

Comment: 'true' is not Boolean, it's a string actually.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the quotes from 'true' seems to have worked - which is strange as the value is no longer a boolean as ToString() has been called